# after changing sources.list on ubuntu, how do I make him reload/refresh?

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, aptitude

after changing sources.list on ubuntu, how do I make him reload/refresh?
So new packages in the new sources will be found?

Comment: So this program is an dude? ;-)

Comment: @Lucas McCoy Did you mean "a dude"? ;-)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
$sudo apt-get update
```

This will update the list of available packages from the server.

Comment: or `sudo aptitude update`